# Encoding Error While Merging Multiple Text Files in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, file, encoding

I want to merge multiple files using python3. All the files are there in a single folder with .txt as extension. 
In the folder, there are files starting with special characters like `dot (.)` and `braces()` etc. The code and dataset are there in separate folders. Please help.

What I have tried is as follows:

```
#encoding:utf-8
import os
from pprint import pprint
path = 'F:/abc/intt'
file_names = os.listdir(path)
with open('F://hi//Datasets//megef_fil.txt', 'w', encoding = 'utf-8') as outfile:
   for fname in file_names:
       with open(os.path.join(path,fname)) as infile:
          for line in infile:
              outfile.write(line)
```

The error in trace which I am facing is something like this.

> File "C:\Users\Shanky\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
>       return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
>   UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8d in position 31: character maps to

I am absolutely not having any clue where I am going wrong. Please help me in fixing this issue. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are all of the files using the same encoding, or are they mixed? If they're the same then it's just a matter of knowing what it is and specifying it consistently. Otherwise open the files in binary mode.

Comment: Okay thanks mark. I guess all the files are of same encoding. Will check.

Answer (score 0):

it's seems to be that you read your inerfile in byte with not the proper encoding, try to do :

```py
with open(os.path.join(path,fname), mode="r", encoding="utf-8") as infile:
```

Comment: Your suggestion not helping me in fixing the issue @Florian. The error still persists. `UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 29-32: character maps to <undefined>`

Comment: did you try with ASCII?